# Laravel Collection#makeVisible() as a method of the Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have some Eloquent Model with **hidden** `payload` field

In some places I want to include that field to JSON representation. I do it with makeVisible method:

```
$models->makeVisible('payload');
```

But I don't think it's good OOP code (SRP, DIP, DRY rules, whatever). I would like to hide it behind some abstraction by having some reusable method, like **withPayload()**, sitting inside my Model class. Is there any way to achieve this in Laravel? Maybe somehow with Query Scopes and pluck method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you're currently using `makeVisible` is fine. You won't be gaining anything by hiding `->makeVisible('payload');` behind another method. It would be a non-standard way of doing things and the next developer would have to go and learn and remember what the new method does.

`$hidden` and `makeVisible` makes it clear to the next developer that the data is possibly sensitive data and must not be visible to all users. If you think you might make the data visible more often than keeping it hidden, consider to either add the field to the `$visible` array or remove both the `$visible` and `$hidden` arrays (if you're not using it for any other fields), and use the  `makeHidden` method to hide the data when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to dive into [fractals](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) 
([spatie/laravel-fractal](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal) is a nice wrapper around that) and put there the logic for representing your model as JSON.

There you can define the base structure of your JSON output (i.e the fields that you always have) and use an *include* wherever you need your specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you're looking for is :

```
Model::setVisible('field')
```

From => [this](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setVisible)